# Jquery Ajax failing to direct data to server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm trying to fix my jquery ajax script which should delete a sql row and also delete two files stored on the server. Currently, when user clicks delete button, the js confirmation message pops up, but upon the user confirming 'yes', the script dies, nothing gets deleted, neither the sql row or the files. the row identifyer is 'id.' How can this be corrected to delete the data and then remove the element containing the data?

html

```
<div class="record<?php echo $id; ?>">
      <form method="POST" id="delete_form">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id" />
        <input type="hidden" id="ad_link" value="<?php echo $ad_link; ?>" name="ad_link" />
        <input type="hidden" id="listing_img" value="<?php echo $listing_img; ?>" name="listing_img" />
        <input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" />
      </form>
</div>
```

js (immediately before )

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        var element = $(this);

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this listing?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_list.php",
                data: {id: element.data("id"), ad_link: element.data("ad_link"), listing_img: element.data("listing_img") },
                success: function() {}
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

php (on different page, delete_list.php)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id']) && ($_POST['ad_link']) || ($_POST['listing_img'])) {
$idc = $_POST['id'];
unlink($_POST['ad_link']);
unlink($_POST['listing_img']);

try {
    require('../dbcon2.php');
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM listings WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($idc));    
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
}
 $url = 'http://website.com/members_area/delete_listings.php';
 while (ob_get_status()) {
  ob_end_clean();
  }
  header("Location: $url");
?>
```

Comment: Try either `<button type="submit" class="delete" name="delete" />Delete</button>` or `<input type="submit" class="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" />` it may not be executing. If that doesn't make it fire up, then I don't know what else it could be. Wait for other possible answers.

Comment: You also have a stray `$sql` variable, so I don't know what that is doing there.

Comment: Check your Ajax call is firing up or not and your post data to

Comment: I played around with the button settings @Fred-ii- last night, with no success, I'm pretty stumped here. Firebug is giving me no clues. By stray sql var do you mean $idc? If i change all $idc to $id, same issue though?

Comment: See `hjpotter92`'s answer below then.

Comment: No, the `$sql` in `echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();` that is undefined. It won't break your code, it's just an undefined and stray variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- embarrassingly that has been starring me in the face for a few days now. thank you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire script (JS) is built on the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    var element = $(this);
```

That is, you're only accessing the `.delete` element for values; whereas they exist inside the parent `form` element. As [Fred suggested](//stackoverflow.com/questions/26949626/jquery-ajax-failing-to-direct-data-to-server#comment42440740_26949626) to use a submit button; try the following:

```
<form method="POST" id="delete_form">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?= $id; ?>" name="id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="ad_link" value="<?= $ad_link; ?>" name="ad_link" />
    <input type="hidden" id="listing_img" value="<?= $listing_img; ?>" name="listing_img" />
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
  </form>
```

and the JS:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var element = $(this);
```

Now; you can simply pass `$(this).serialize()` inside the AJAX request.

Comment: Let's cross our fingers ;) I've asked the OP to check your answer. JS is really not my strongest point in coding.

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- so the logic in here makes perfect sense, .serialize seems ideal, I'm checking API and it's unclear where/how in the AJAX req to include it. Also it is completely dependent on successful controls, There could times where the files will be null. Can you recommended where to place .serialize? Do you see this being an issue for null values?

Comment: @Rhillz http://devdocs.io/jquery/serialize You'll use it in AJAX as follows: `$.ajax( { type: 'POST', url: "delete_list.php", data: $(this).serialize(), ...`

Comment: @hjpotter92 WOW! what an easier way to pass form data!! Here's a caviete with this though. How do i pull out the id now and use it to selector to delete the right element after ajax success. For instance if I wanted to $(element).remove() ???

Comment: @Rhillz `$(this).children('#id').val()`

Comment: Another happy ending.